# Running custom container images based on platform certified images jelastic/springboot:correttojdk-17.0.8.7.1 failure: "...No such file or directory"

Tags: spring-boot, docker-container, docker-image, jelastic

I want to run my custom docker image on hidora based on [platform certified images](https://hub.docker.com/u/jelastic) [jelastic/springboot:correttojdk-17.0.8.7.1](https://hub.docker.com/layers/jelastic/springboot/correttojdk-17.0.8.7.1/images/sha256-de108fe44c3a45d0583a008277fd65db03c14af27fd50f5d90650a93c0e6eb71?context=explore) as recommended in [Setting Up Environment](https://www.virtuozzo.com/application-platform-docs/setting-up-environment/) guide. I tested this locally with docker by running a custom container of a simple hello word web service built with gradle and spring boot 3 and it failed despite all the articles  I read ([Building Custom Container](https://www.virtuozzo.com/application-platform-docs/building-custom-container/),
[Getting Started with Amazon Corretto 17 on Docker Images](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-17-ug/docker-install.html),
[Generate Single Jar Or War In Spring Boot App Using Gradle Build Tool](https://roytuts.com/generate-single-jar-or-war-in-spring-boot-app-using-gradle-build-tool/) and [how to dockerize a Spring Boot application](https://anywhere.epam.com/en/blog/how-to-dockerize-spring-boot-application)).

- I'd generated a fat jar that I'd tested, and that works fine.
- Then I'd created a docker file that contains the following lines:

```
FROM jelastic/springboot:correttojdk-17.0.8.7.1
COPY build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar dockerimage.jar
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/dockerimage.jar"]
```

- Then I had built the docker image by the following command lines:

```
docker build . -t dockerimagejelsprgboot:v1.0
```

- Then I had run a container based on the created image via docker desktop interface.

I expected to it would work fine (because I had already used other image and there was no problem) but this one failed. The container exits with this log: "2023-08-14 22:28:19 /usr/bin/java: line 73: /java.orig: No such file or directory" and I'm lost. A little help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the jelastic image requires putting our .jar file in a specific directory: "/home/jelastic/APP/" i.e. Dockerfile becomes:

```
FROM jelastic/springboot:correttojdk-17.0.8.7.1
COPY build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /home/jelastic/APP/dockerimage.jar
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/home/jelastic/APP/dockerimage.jar"]
```